# istio gateway stops working when using subdomain in virtualservice

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, istio-gateway, servicemesh

have this GCP load balancer within a GKE Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gcp-loadbalancer-ingress
  namespace: istio-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "*.foo.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: istio-ingressgateway
                port:
                  number: 80
```

The istio gateway looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
  namespace: istio-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
    - "*.foo.com"
```

And virtual service:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: sample-app
  namespace: istio-ingress
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  # - "app.foo.com" If replace above with this it stops working
  gateways:
  - gateway
  http:
  - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: /
    route:
      - destination:
          host: sample-app
```

How can I limit so `sample-app` `virtualservice` only routes when route is `app.foo.com`

### Update

Wondering if the issue has to do something with my `istio-ingressgateway`:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-ingress
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: istio-ingressgateway
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.20.0
    helm.sh/chart: gateway-1.20.0
    istio: ingressgateway
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: istio-ingressgateway
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: istio-ingress
spec:
  ports:
  - name: status-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 15021
    targetPort: 15021
    nodePort: 30276
  - name: http-web
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31849
  - name: https-ssl
    protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    nodePort: 30824
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
  clusterIP: {IP}
  clusterIPs:
  - {IP}
  type: NodePort
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use a [service entry](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Destination) to access external service or site, see sample as below, you can see this one also on the docs link:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-svc-site
spec:
  hosts:
  - external-site.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: example-https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-external-site-rule
spec:
  hosts:
  - external-site.com
  http:
  - timeout: 5s
    route:
    - destination:
        host: external-site.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Istio's Gateway resource if you're using the Ingress resource. You can pick one. If you must use the Ingress resource, you can use the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: istio` annotation on the Ingress to use the istio-ingressgateway as your controller.  (Check the docs here: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/)

If you don't have to use the Ingress resource, use the Istio's Gateway resource.

If you want to "expose" the sample-app through the Gateway, you have to ensure the following:

1. You add the Gateway name to the `gateways` field (which you have)
2. You match the host name in the Gateway resource with the host name in the VirtualService (i.e. add `app.foo.bar` to the hosts field in the VirtualService).